# Thumbnail Cropping with add_image_size?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I want my thumbnails on a particular page to be `300px` × `100px`, exactly.  Currently, images shrink until they hit the 300 pixel or 100 pixel mark.  How do I get the image to crop to exactly 300 × 100 (preferably without image distortion).

```
// functions.php:
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'post-thumb', 620, 207, true );
    add_image_size( 'home-thumb', 220, 180, true );
    add_image_size( 'index-thumb', 300, 100, true );
}
// index.php:
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('index-thumb');
```

Comment: The images that are shrinking must be the images that were uploaded before you specified these sizes? or you are having issues with newer uploads too? Because the true parameter actually crops the image with out distorting them.

Comment: I have it set to true but the image does not crop to 300 by 100.  Its crops to 300 by X pixels or to Y pixels by 100. Whichever comes first.

Comment: That is how WP crops, for the exact 300x100 crop, check the solution at: http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/1098. NOTE:I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Been having the same issues, found this and its working for me - http://sumtips.com/2011/12/custom-image-sizes-in-wordpress.html

Answer (score 4):

Refer to [the **`add_image_size()`** Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size):

```
<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

The **`$crop`** parameter is the key:

> *(boolean) (optional)* Crop the image or not. False - Soft proportional crop mode ; True - Hard crop mode.
>
> Default: false

That is:

- **False** (default): *box-resize* - (resize image against the constraining dimension)
- **True**: *hard-crop* - crop the image *exactly* to the specified dimensions

Thus your code should work:

```
// Add Theme support
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

// Register custom image sizes
add_image_size( 'post-thumb', 620, 207, true );
add_image_size( 'home-thumb', 220, 180, true );
add_image_size( 'index-thumb', 300, 100, true );
```

If you find that your images are not being rendered/displayed properly, there are a couple of things to verify:

- For images added *prior to* implementation of these custom image sizes, you will need to **regenerate the thumbnails** for those images
- Image sizes *will not be generated* for images that are not at least as large as the specified dimensions of a given image size. Thus, ensure that your images are at least as large as your largest-specified hard-crop image size. (Box-resized images are not as constrained, and only need to be at least as large as the *smallest* dimension of a given image size.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this [plugin](http://demo.ad-theme.com/plugin/imager/)

- it creates unlimited image sizes (cropped and not)
- it adds sizes on media select field
- it adds css filtering and animations
- it can manage watermarks

Answer (score -1):

Try to Change the "ture" paramater to "false" .
You can also remove the "if" statements on the functions php if they are not needed for something else...

Comment: The true parameter actually crops the image, if you will make it false the image will not be cropped, it will be resized instead.

Comment: Marking it true or false gives me the same result.

Comment: did you made sure that your images are actually Bigger than sizes you defined as thumbs ? and did you try to remove the "if" clauses ??

Comment: I did try larger images.  Same result.  Removing the if clauses gives an error.

Comment: can you give the error ?